# Issue with linking sublink which is loading content using javascript

Tags: javascript

The page containing more sub links,That sublink content is loading using JavaScript... Now I want to load that particular sublink content from another page, Can you help on this?

Comment: Add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use JS frameworks (like `Vue.js`, `React.js` or `Angular.js`)

Start with `Vue.js`. It has pretty simply syntax and it's easy to learn.

Also read about SPA ([Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application))

Luck)